# Java says "ghidra" is unknown protocol when creating project on linux

Tags: ghidra

**Update:** I installed Eclipse and PyDev in Linux and my code works now. This confirms it was an issue setting up the Python/Jython paths. I would still like to know how to import ghidra.jar into jython so that I can use the command line in the future. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

I am making a ghidra project on Linux. I am using a Ghidra jar and jython to code my application. I am adding ghidra to my path with system.path.append() and I am running my program with
`jython main.py`.

My code worked with Pydev in Eclipse on Windows, but on Linux I am getting

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: ghidra

when I reach `ghidraProject.createProject()`. I investigated the source and I found that the error occurs when Java tries to [make a url](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) from a string. I know Ghidra has a [protocol handler](http://ghidra.re/ghidra_docs/api/ghidra/framework/protocol/ghidra/Handler.html) which should be handling the protocol "ghidra". I assume Java doesn't register the protocol handler somehow. I tried `Handler.registerHandler()` with no luck.

Why is "ghidra" an unknown protocol on Linux, but the same code works (save for the PyDev environment) in Eclipse/Windows?

Error printout:
[image]

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to use Ghidra without initializing it first, Ghidra isn't really designed as a typical Java library which you could use like any other `.jar`. If you want to check out how the Ghidra provided `pythonRun` entry point handles a minimal jython REPL embedded inside Ghidra, check out: https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/da94eb86bd2b89c8b0ab9bd89e9f0dc5a3157055/Ghidra/Features/Python/src/main/java/ghidra/python/PythonRun.java

The crucial part here is:

```java
ApplicationConfiguration configuration = new HeadlessGhidraApplicationConfiguration();
Application.initializeApplication(layout, configuration);
```

which runs through various initialization steps that the overall Ghidra code assumes to have happened when being executed, one of them being the setup for the `ghidra://` protocol handler.
Specifically the call to `ghidra.framework.protocol.ghidra.Handler.registerHandler()` happens inside `ghidra.ProjectInitializer#run`.

Comment: I initialized the application in my code:


`configuration = HeadlessGhidraApplicationConfiguration() configuration.setInitializeLogging(False)
 Application.initializeApplication(GhidraJarApplicationLayout(), configuration)`

I think the issue is that I'm not replicating how PyDev creates the Jython environment.

Comment: I'd need more details on your project and how you are starting it then, especially if your Eclipse/PyDev install has the Ghidra Dev plugin installed